# Solicitar cantidad de variables y darles nombre

Tags: c++, c

Estoy aprendiendo a programar en c++ y necesitaba saber si es posible crear un algoritmo que solicite al usuario la cantidad de variables que va a utilizar, y luego nombrarlas.

Muy agradecido por sus respuestas

Saludos

Comment: Sí, es posible.   Debes publicar lo que has hecho. y qué problema tienes.

Comment: @anibaltsz Si, es posible, diviértete codificandolo. :)